# Saving Dynamic Data in Objects?

Tags: javascript, object, row

I have a simple time entry form, see here: https://codepen.io/dikuw/pen/rmpozm

I want to store the time data dynamically as the user adds, modifies, and deletes rows and am thinking objects is the best approach.

My question is what is the best practice? Should I create a constructor, e.g.

```
function TimesheetRecord(id, TSDate, TSStaffId, Hours, Comments, TSTaskId, Billable) {
    this.id = id;
    this.TSDate = TSDate;
    this.TSStaffId = TSStaffId;
    this.Hours = Hours;
    this.Comments = Comments;
    this.TSTaskId = TSTaskId;
    this.Billable = Billable;
}
```

and then dynamically create a new object every time the user adds a row? If I do that, how will I know how many objects there are?

Comment: For creating simple objects `{ 'key' : value }` notation would be much easier and fast also.

Comment: Use a `set` or `array` to store the objects and then count elements inside.

Comment: put them into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can create an Array to store your all TimesheetRecords and push a new dynamic object when you create a new one.

```
// When app starts (dataFromDB is data fetched from db if any)
const TimesheetRecords = dataFromDB || []

// create a new record(mainly in a function)
const TimesheetRecord = {
   id: id,
   TSDate: TSDate,
   TSStaffId: TSStaffId,
   Hours: Hours,
   Comments: Comments,
   TSTaskId: TSTaskId,
   Billable: Billable
}

// store to db (ajax) and then push to array
TimesheetRecords.push(TimesheetRecord)

// Check how many records are there
const count = TimesheetRecords.length
```

This is common pattern for storing simple objects without any behaviors(methods) in JavaScript.